# inline code is filling the space to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the [pydata-sphinx-theme](https://github.com/pydata/pydata-sphinx-theme) and we are facing a css issue in our 0.13 release : the css inline code is filling the space to the right.

In short we flavored inline code using the `<code>` tag and for a strange reason the space to the right is filled as inline code as well. The generated html is as dollowed in the source by Shpinx (I intentionally left it as it is in the file in case it's a just a matter of indentation):

```html
<li class="toc-h2 nav-item toc-entry"><a class="reference internal nav-link" href="#the-gallery-grid-directive">The <code class="docutils literal notranslate"><span class="pre">gallery-grid</span></code> directive</a></li>
```

and the shown result can be seen in the secondary sidebar of this [page](https://pydata-sphinx-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/community/topics.html#the-gallery-grid-directive):

[image]

anyone could explain why the css is extending to the space placed on the right side?

### note

I don't know what css would be relevant to share, I'll update the question if someone want more specific insight

Comment: This seems to work fine on my windows 10 pc running Chrome 108.0.5359.125 64bit. Did ou try other browsers?

Comment: Working for me in Firefox. Are you sure that space is outside the `<code>` element?

Comment: We need the CSS, could you provide it in a minimal reproducible example ?

Comment: I would love to provide a minimal reproducible example but the page is generated so the css comes from everywhere. I'll try my best to create a codepen but last time I asked a similar question I didn't manage. 
I tried safari/chrome/firefox and I get the same result and I'm 100% sure the space is outside the <code> element I copy/paster the line from the source

Comment: My hope was that it was some kind of issue like the space between inline element and not css related

Comment: 'so the CSS comes from everywhere' - understood, but have you used you browser devtools to inspect exactly what CSS is being applied? It should be possible to work out where it's coming from and what is producing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, unfortunatelly the solution was hidden deeper than the html/css rendering.

For anyone dropping by:

The Sphinx framework is using `prettify()` from `beautifulsoup` to output the production website. The paradigm is to put each tag on a single line including all the inline ones, creating extra spaces everywhere.

So the real rendered HTM was:

```html
<li class="toc-h2 nav-item toc-entry">
  <a class="reference internal nav-link" href="#the-gallery-grid-directive">
   The
   <code class="docutils literal notranslate">
    <span class="pre">
     gallery-grid
    </span>
   </code>
   directive
  </a>
 </li>
```

preventing the prettify action I got the uglier but working line I set in the question.

```html
<li class="toc-h2 nav-item toc-entry">
  <a class="reference internal nav-link" href="#the-gallery-grid-directive">The <code class="docutils literal notranslate"><span class="pre">gallery-grid</span></code> directive</a>
</li>
```

[image]

Here is a small codepen to see the diff between the 2 configs: https://codepen.io/12rambau/pen/NWBdKYr